# How to insert the id from 1 table to another at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables login and users. in table login i have user_id(primary key), username(varchar),password(varchar) and in table users id(primary key),username(varchar),user_id(int)..what i want to happen is that when i insert a record in table login the user_id should be inserted also in user_id in table users..please help me with it..

**Here's my code for insertion**

```
public function create($username,$password,$province)
{
try
{
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO login(username,password,province) VALUES(:username, :password, :province)");
  $stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
  $stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
  $stmt->bindparam(":province",$province);
  $stmt->execute();

$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO sample(username) VALUES (:username)");

 $stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
 $stmt->execute();
 return true;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();  
  return false;
}
}
```

As of now what i done is inserting a record into tables at the same time..but i'm kinda struggling on how to insert the user_id from table login to user_id in table users..

Comment: @Fred-ii- i'm sorry its a bad paste

Comment: Your tables are `login` and `sample`; so `user_id from table login to user_id in table users` doesn't make sense. Is `user_id` auto-incrementing in `login`? If so maybe start here, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php.

Comment: yes.the user_id in login table is autoincrement

Comment: and `sample` is `users`? Use the `lastinsertid`. I don't know why you need `sample` or `users` table though, seems like all the data is already in `login`..

Comment: the user_id in the sample table is set to integer..what i want is that when i insert a record in login table the user_id from login should also be inserted in user_id in sample table

Comment: Okay, and you tried what I've said and it isn't working? A trigger as noted below would work. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html `The keyword INSERT indicates the trigger event; that is, the type of operation that activates the trigger. In the example, INSERT operations cause trigger activation.`

Comment: @chris85 can you please help me solve this.because i'm just a newbie in PDO and i'm struggling with this one..

Comment: Your question is becoming less clear. What you said you want your code doesn't have. I've provided docs for how you can do this; I can't write code when pertinent information is missing/scattered.

Comment: @chris85 it's working now thanks for the advice and for the manual..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [`PDO::lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) -> `$this->db->lastInsertId();`

```
public function create($username,$password,$province)
{
try
{
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO login(username,password,province) VALUES(:username, :password, :province)");
  $stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
  $stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
  $stmt->bindparam(":province",$province);
  $stmt->execute();

  $user_id = $this->db->lastInsertId(); 

  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO sample(username,user_id) VALUES (:username, :user_id)");
  $stmt->bindparam(":user_id",$user_id);
  $stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
  $stmt->execute();
  return true;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();  
  return false;
}
}
```

Alternatively you could do a `INSERT ... SELECT ...` query,
which would look like -

```
INSERT INTO sample(username,user_id) SELECT :username, user_id FROM login WHERE username = :username1
```

so your function would look like -

```
public function create($username,$password,$province)
{
try
{
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO login(username,password,province) VALUES(:username, :password, :province)");
  $stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
  $stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
  $stmt->bindparam(":province",$province);
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO sample(username,user_id) SELECT  :username, user_id FROM login WHERE username = :username1");
  $stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
  $stmt->bindparam(":username1",$username);
  $stmt->execute();
  return true;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();  
  return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `$user_id`

make changes to the function like this

```
public function create($username,$password,$province)
{
try
{
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO login(username,password,province) VALUES(:username, :password, :province)");
  $stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
  $stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
  $stmt->bindparam(":province",$province);
  $stmt->execute();
   // make changes here create $user_id
$user_id =  $this->db->insert_id;
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO sample(username,user_id) VALUES (:username, :user_id)");
    // make changes here in user_id instead of user_i
 $stmt->bindparam(":user_id",$user_id);

 $stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
 $stmt->execute();
 return true;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();  
  return false;
}
}
```

Comment: by the way what is the insert_id?

Comment: @MeeneshJain [`$stmt->insert_id;`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) is a `mysqli` method. OP is using PDO so it should be [`$this->db->lastInsertId();`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: @sean so what do i need to do?

Comment: have you tried `$user_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();` in place of `$user_id =  $stmt->insert_id;` that this poster did?

Comment: yes..i already replace that line..but still not working..when i try to remove the user_id in the sample table and try to insert record its inserting on both table but not the user_id

Comment: @sean by the way the user_id in sample table is set to int is there somthing to do with that?why it's not inserting the user_id

Comment: if it is not inserting into the `sample` table, it is because you don't have the `user_id` value from your insert into your `login` table. You need to figure out why you are not getting that value.

Comment: Do i need to put the user_id to the login table?because user_id in login table is set to auto increment.do i still need to put that?

Comment: @Sean thanks for the correction i will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create database trigger like

```
Create or replace trigger <trigger_name> after insert login ...
```

In which you  on insert of first table you can insert record in another table with same id. You can create trigger as specified 
[Here](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php)

Comment: but how can i do that?i'm sorry but i'm just a newbie in PDO

Comment: You will have to use new.user_id as value in another table..read this post https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html